# Missing Local File supplementalData.xml

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I have been recently developing a Magento site and came across a weird issue. The site I developed was in the /staging folder and when I tried to move shift it to the root folder, the keeps showing the following error.

Things already done:

1. Updated the domain name in core_config_data
2. Cleared everything under VAR folder
3. Checked .htaccess file
4. Compiler disabled

I am not sure why it adds /staging in the error below

Please note: I uploaded a fresh version of the lib folder and the below error seems to get fixed, but then the Submit Order button redirects me to the Shopping Cart page.

```
Missing locale file '/chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/supplementalData.xml' for 'supplementalData' locale
Trace:
0 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php(231): Zend_Locale_Data::_findRoute('supplementalDat...', '/supplementalDa...', 'iso4217', 'US', Array)
1 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php(1206): Zend_Locale_Data::_getFile('supplementalDat...', '/supplementalDa...', 'iso4217', 'US')

2 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/lib/Zend/Currency.php(323): Zend_Locale_Data::getContent('en_US', 'currencytoregio...', 'US')
3 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/lib/Zend/Currency.php(375): Zend_Currency->_checkParams(NULL, 'en_US')
4 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/lib/Zend/Currency.php(569): Zend_Currency->getShortName(NULL, 'en_US')
5 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/lib/Zend/Currency.php(106): Zend_Currency->setLocale(NULL)
6 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(588): Zend_Currency->__construct('SEK')
7 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(270): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->currency('SEK')
8 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(242): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt('0.00000000', Array)
9 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(222): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatPrecision('0.00000000', 2, Array, true, false)
10 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(82): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->format('0.00000000')
11 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(62): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->format('0.00000000')
12 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Totals.php(74): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->addTotal('Int\xC3\xA4kt\xA4kt'0.00000000')
13 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Totals->_prepareLayout()
14 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
15 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php(50): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
16 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
17 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
18 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#19 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
20 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
21 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
22 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
23 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
24 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
25 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
26 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
27 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
28 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
29 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
30 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
31 /chroot/home/domain/mydomain.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
32 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

A step to recheck : go to phpmyadmin and search if "/staging" is present in any of the table entries.

Comment: Already did that and it no table shows up with staging as a word or domain in it.